# How to force pyinstaller to use raw .py files for quick update without recreating exe?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a big project, and I update it very often.

Later I used py2exe one time to create the main .exe file, and just copied only 1-2 fresh .py files after every update to the directory with .exe file (no need to recreate .exe file, really quick update).

But I can't force pyinstaller to use my raw .py files this way. It packs all .py files to .exe and on running it extract and use that files. So I should recreate .exe even after the smallest changes of code (and it takes too long time...).

How to force pyinstaller to use my .py files like I did with py2exe?

Comment: You can't. Pyinstaller makes bytecodes of the Python code. It doesn't put raw Python into the `.exe`. Bundling a Python program into an `.exe` should be the very last step of a deployment. If you are still debugging the Python then making an `.exe` out of it is premature.

Comment: * If you are still debugging the Python then making an .exe out of it is premature
This is really close, I've described why. I code and always make a lot of changes, but people on windows machines actively use that program now.